# Colimits in $Ch_R$, help with a step of the proof

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra

I want to prove that the category of chain complexes of R-modules admits small colimits. I was told to try proving that the chain complex defined degree wise as the colimit of the modules of the same degree is the colimit of a given diagram. I built the boundary operator following this hint found on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61530/boundary-operator-in-the-colimit-of-complexes), but now I'm stuck in proving that such complex has indeed the universal property. I took another cone $C$ (With module indexed $C_k$) over my diagram $D(n)$ (each $D(n)$ is a chain complex), and noticed that **degree-wise** I have unique maps 
$$i_k \colon \text{Colim}_n D(n)_k \to C_k$$

this is indeed my candidate for the map from the Colim to $C$ But I'm **unable** to prove that it is indeed a map of chain complexes!

Can someone help me with the proof?

Comment: Why does it not work? This is simply a matter of chasing the definitions.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg maybe my problem was that I didn't use what a colimit in Mod is. maybe I figured out a solution, later I'll upload what I think I got

Comment: You can use explicit constructions if you want. But this is not necessary. In fact, if $C$ is any pointed category (so that we can talk about chain complexes in $C$), which is also cocomplete, then the category $\mathrm{Ch}(C)$ of chain complexes in $C$ is cocomplete, too. If you really want to understand what's going on here, you will have to prove this more general result. It's not hard.

Comment: Use the uniqueness of the degree-wise induced maps to conclude that they commute with the boundary operators.